# Using Spring Data Specifications, how do you compare a division of two columns with some input value?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-data, relational-database

I'm having trouble writing Spring Data Specification which is supposed to filter out some rows out of DB search query.

Suppose there is a table in a database. This table contains two columns both of which have int type. I need a Spring Data Specification which would filter by division of those two columns. So if those columns are A and B, then a need to compare A/B with some known input value.

Here is what I'm trying to do (I'm using Kotlin)

```
return Specification { root: Root<Payment>, _: CriteriaQuery<*>?, builder: CriteriaBuilder ->
        val settlement: Join<Payment, Settlement> = root.join("settlement", JoinType.INNER)

        val decimalExpression = settlement.get<Long>("decimal")
        val multiplierExpression = settlement.get<Long>("multiplier")
        val divisionExpression : Expression<Number> = builder.quot(decimalExpression, multiplierExpression)
        builder.and(
                builder.isNotNull(decimalExpression),
                builder.isNotNull(multiplierExpression),
                builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
                        divisionExpression,
                        someKnownLongValue
                ))
    }
```

So `settlement` is my table. The fact that its some kind of join is not important right now.

Columns  `decimal` and `multiplier` are my A and B columns (I also don't need any of them to be null, otherwise I can't divide). This looks like it should work, but there is a problem I'm encountering, because the types to be compared must implement `Comparable` and `CriteriaBuilder#quot()` methods return type is `Expression<Number>`. The class `Number` is not comparable. It looks like some class casts are needed? But I'm not sure how to go about it and what is the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good workaround, instead of dividing, you can just multiply both parts of the equation, that way you dont have to deal with 'Number' class

```
val multipliedExpression = builder.prod(settlement.get<Long>("multiplier"), someKnownLongValue)
builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
    settlement.get<Long>("decimal"),
    multipliedExpression
)
```